# Running MiniZInc with 2 Dzn file at the same time

Tags: python, scheduling, constraint-programming, minizinc, multiple-assignment

Currently, I'm doing some project for college scheduling using MiniZinc. I use 2 dzn files which are A.dzn and B.dzn, these dzn file are filled with college data such as student_groups, subject, num of class, etc.

I want to run the mzn file for the model, but it can't run because "Multiple Assignment to the same variable". Is there any solution for this problem?

Thank you

I've tried run the model with command line `minizinc --allow-multiple-assignments Model.mzn A.dzn A.dzn` but still can't run the model with two dzn files or more.

Answer (score 0):

Minizinc can run with 2 (or more) dzn files. However this works on assumption that the dzn contains different variables that are assigned to data. I think you are getting the error due to variable(s) being assign in both the dzn files. Remove variables that occur in both the files, they should only be assign one time in either file, not both.